# Prove a particular set (rectangle) is closed and bounded

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $A = \{(x,y): 5x+4y \leq 20, x \geq 2, y \geq 1\}$. With the usual Euclidean metric $d$, prove that $A$ is bounded and closed on $(X,d)$. Is $A$ compact?

My attempt: $A = \{(x,y): 2 \leq x \leq \frac{16}{5} ,  1 \leq y \leq \frac{5}{2} \}$. So let $r_0 = \sqrt{(\frac{16}{5})^2 + (\frac{5}{2})^2 }$, choose $r> r_0$, then the open ball S with center $(0,0)$ and radius $r$ always contains $A$. Thus $A$ is bounded.

$\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash A = \{(x,y):  x <2 \ \text{or} \ x> \frac{16}{5} ,  y <1 \ \text{or} \ y >\frac{5}{2} \}$. Since this set is open, $A$ is closed.

$A$ is compact because $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a complete space, then any bounded and closed set is compact.

Is the proof correct and rigorous enough?

Comment: Wrong! The last part of your proof is wrong. In a complete metric space a closed and bounded set  need not be compact. Instead of bringing in completeness you have to quote the well-known result that closed and bounded subsets of $\mathbb R^{n}$ are compact.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг A metric space is compact iff it is complete and totally bounded...so I don't believe such a proof exists.

Comment: @Math1000 You are right. I phrased it incorrectly. I will remove the previous comment.